# Swift 3 : Extra argument 'error' in call

Tags: ios, swift

I have tried all solutions like try catch. But not able to solve this error. Please help me out, I am new to ios.

```
func apicalling () {

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "7adebcbe-18b4-d2a7-2159-2fbcaea27edd"
    ]
    let parameters = [
        "customerID": "1",
        "listType": "2"
    ]

    let postData = JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: nil)



    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://exp.php")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.HTTPBody = postData

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()

       }
```

The error in this below line :

```
let postData = JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: nil)
```

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In swift 3, it will be:

```
do {
  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options:[])
  // do your works
} catch {
  print("Got error: \(error)")
}
```

The API document is here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 3, you need to add `do, with try and catch`, also the `error` argument got deleted, since it will throw now error, because it will get caught.

```
func apicalling () {

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "postman-token": "7adebcbe-18b4-d2a7-2159-2fbcaea27edd"
    ]
    let parameters = [
        "customerID": "1",
        "listType": "2"
    ]
    do {
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options :[])
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://exp.php")! as URL,
                                      cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        request.httpBody = postData

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
    } catch {
        print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
    }
}
```